# 500 internal server error after php file x second running, how to understand reason

Tags: php, excel, apache, error-log

I have shared hosting.

I have some php code and after approximately 40 second running, returned `500 internal server error`.

This is info according to `phpinfo()`:

```
Directive          | Local Value | Master Value
-------------------------------------------------- 
max_execution_time | 0           | 120
-------------------------------------------------- 
memory_limit       | 16384M      | 16384M
```

When I look error log file (In cPanel, `Logs` section `Error log` file), there is no info, why internal server error happens, (there is other logs).

So, what may be causes this error? how to understand reason? there is possible without contact to host provider?

Comment: Your webserver is also likely to have a time limit for responding to requests

Comment: What does the error_reporting value say in `phpinfo()`?

Comment: there might also be `suhosin` time and ressource limits. but it looks like you got a recursive or never-ending loop in your script. can you provide more explanation and information please

Comment: @DanFromGermany -- recursive scripts would yield a "Fatal error" with "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached".

Comment: Also if the server were taking too long (while in the never ending loop) it would't yield a 500 error, it would yield a "no reply" error.

Comment: @MarkBaker - can you tell please what directive is this?  @silkfire - local value for error reporting is `-1`

Comment: @OTARIKI Hmm, usually a 500 error could mean that PHP errored out, but if errors are disabled, you will see a default 500 error page instead. If you have rights to create .htaccess files, you can make one with the following lines: `php_flag display_errors On[line break here]php_value error_reporting 30719` (not sure it will help though).

Comment: @DanFromGermany - This is not never-ending loop, this script generates xls file, if generated rows count < approximately  20 0000, then works, othervise gives error.

Comment: @OTARIKI This could be a memory issue. Generating Excel files of that kind of size requires huge amount of memory, especially if you use PHPExcel library (as it is the only one I know that generates XLSX files).

Comment: @silkfire - Yes, I use PHPExcel library.  That is, may be even   16384M   is not  enough memory size?

Comment: Why do the Excel files have to be so large? Can you split up the data on multiple sheets?

Comment: If you're working with larger workbooks using PHPExcel, I'd always recommend executing it as a background process, not run it directly within a web request; and if memory is the problem, then use cell caching to reduce memory usage (though at a cost in performance)

Answer (score 0):

Usually an Error 500 is getting triggered by a wrong configuration of the HTTPD Server, If you have a .htaccess please double check it , Or you can just paste here your php code in order to let us determine this issue...

Comment: Wrong configurations of the .htaccess would yield a 500 error immediately, it wouldn't take time to run & load.

Comment: Also it would be applicable to every URL within that folder.

Comment: Except if there's a rewrite rule for the specific file... also if htaccess and this php file is in a specific folder, would have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without actually seeing code, but it seems like server fails to handle either memory leaks or stack overflow correctly. First, try enabling all the error reporting in your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: I am trying this but result is same, just typical `500 internal server error` message is returned.

Comment: Try localizing by gradually commenting out parts of script. Then put offending part here.